# OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I have this error :
OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - mat data type = 18 is not supported
> - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'

with this code :

```
fname = "img.jpeg"
    for i in range (0,10):
        f = open(fname, "wb")
        buf = np.array(ws.recv())
        f.write(buf)
        f.flush()
        f.close()
        cv2.imshow('frame', buf)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    ws.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

If someone can understand this error, it would help me a lot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.imshow` doesn't support binary buffers with image data. The respective image format has to be unpacked and arranged in a proper shape as raw data. To do this don't implement your own import procedure but use `cv2.imread` and you get the image data in a format that `opencv` can process:

```
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
cv2.imshow('frame', img)
```